# Accessing Physical Memory via a High Level Language e.g. 

Tags: c#, memory, dump, ram, memory-dump

I am researching the best way to perform a dump of the memory (RAM) of a Windows 7 machine via a high level programming language e.g. C#. I have done a fair amount of research into this as I will summarize below.

*•It appears that Microsoft API access to memory was cut off some time back (\Device\PhysicalMemory)*

•*It now appears that to gain access to the memory your code must be executed in kernel mode as opposed to user mode to allow you to access the memory*

•*I have looked into how Windows dump’s memory (Small, Large & Kernel dumps) upon a system hang, this method is not suitable for my requirements*

I wondered if anyone had a good take upon how I should go about accessing the physical memory of a machine. My knowledge of low level coding languages is scarce as I am used to programming Window Applications. Suggestions I have received so far would include writing a driver to access the memory and then calling this via a higher level programming language.

Any help that any of the community can offer would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: What will you do with the dump?  Is procdump -ma not sufficient in your environment?

Comment: Accessing physical memory is hard even with low-level languages. The suggestion you received is most likely the sanest approach.

Comment: My search had lead me to procdump -ma but unfortunately it only allows you to dump the memory of a single process. I am looking at accessing the full memory including the files loaded by the OS etc. I would be grateful to see if anyone has any other suggestion or as Mat stated I may need to go down the driver route. noonnb & Justin I have acted upon your recommendation. Cheers

Comment: If this was possible in user mode it would be a security disaster.  If you could write memory as well it would be a protection and security disaster.  You need a driver. 'My knowledge of low level coding languages is scarce' - you should maybe avoid this task, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use [procdump -ma](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900).  This gives complete state of a single process.  Leave debugging the OS to kernel-mode people.

From my rather short experience with kernel-mode debugging with WinDBG, I'd recommend starting with a second PC and a Firewire link.  On the system under test, remove hard drive and install the OS with symbols.  Make sure you have a good base image of the OS with symbols, for the time when you break it.

On my short list of WinDBG books to read is "Programming the Windows Driver Model," Oney, MSPress.

[This may help.](http://www.moonsols.com/windows-memory-toolkit/)